# Laplace transform of $\frac{d^{n}}{d t^{n}} \delta(t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

What is the Laplace transform of $$f(t)=\frac{d^{n}}{d t^{n}} \delta(t)$$, where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac-Delta distribution.

I am really not sure, but i am expecting that by using the formula:
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{f^{(n)}\right\}=s^{n} \mathcal{L}\{f\}-s^{n-1} f(0)-s^{n-2} f^{\prime}(0)-s^{n-3} f^{\prime \prime}(0)-\ldots-f^{(n-1)}(0)$$, we have
$$\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{d^{n}}{d t^{n}} \delta(t)\right)=s^n(1)-0-0-0...-0=s^n$$

But Mathematically how to prove formally that all the derivatives are zeros?

Comment: But this is not differentiable anywhere.

Comment: So Laplace transform does not exist?

Comment: Your result is correct (with some usual assumptions), but proving it formally requires a knowledge of distributions and a definition of Laplace transform for distributions. Informally, one could think of the Laplace transform as defined by $\lim_{t_0 \uparrow 0} \int_{t_0}^\infty$ and evaluate the integral (informally) inductively using integration by parts.

Comment: Why is algebra-precalc a tag here? Question seems way too advanced in my opinion...